# Flashing ESP8266 ESP-12E/12F

Tags: arduino-uno, esp8266, ftdi

I'm pretty new to Arduino programming and i'm trying to connect this ESP8266 module to my FTDI programmer but constantly getting this error on my ARDUINO IDE:  **esptool.FatalError: Failed to connect to ESP8266: Timed out waiting for packet header**.
My guess is that its not in flashing mode and that i have to connect GPIO0 to ground or sompthing else.

[image: /]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On my version of this "Adatper" adapter the io pins were not connected. I patched io 0 to the esp-01 like header, to be able to put the ESP in bootloader mode. On the picture you see a paperclip jumper connecting io 0 to ground for flashing mode.

Back then I could leave the jumper connected, because the esp8266 run the sketch after upload. In new versions of esp8266 arduino boards package the esptool hard resets the esp8266 so it returns into flashing mode. [This can be changed in platform.txt.](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/65628/mega-esp8266-comms-sending-baffling-data/65638#65638)

I recommend you to buy an esp8266 dev board with USB (Wemos, NodeMcu and similar)

[image]
[image]

Comment: I connected it like this [Check here](https://imgur.com/pRfOdUS) but i still got same error TRACE +0.101 Timed out waiting for packet header. Any advice ? :S

Comment: is the io 0 pin of the esp-12F module connected to the header? on my it was not. do you see the wire soldered to esp-12F pin on my photo?

Comment: It's not, since i'm new to this can you explain to me how to connect it to header ?

Comment: you see it on my picture

Comment: I see soldered wire but I do not know where the other end of the wire is going

Comment: I connected wires as on the picture and connected io 0 pin of the esp-12F module to GPO0 on the bottom side of the esp-12 and when i tried to upload the code got this [Check here](https://imgur.com/kFyfSOV)

Comment: I added a photo of the bottom side. Do you still have the jumper wire on the header from Ground to io 0?

Comment: Thank you alot for your help but i still got this error: [link](https://imgur.com/kFyfSOV)

Comment: measure with multi-meter if the soldering and header connection is good

Comment: I think connections are good since Arduino IDE at start uploading shows that he read bytes and receives packet but after a while it crashes like on link :S

Comment: try it without breadboard

Comment: Same result [link](https://imgur.com/kFyfSOV) :/

Comment: do you supply 3.3 or 5 V to the adapter?

Comment: I supply with 3.3V

Comment: the adapter converts 5 V input to 3.3 V for the esp8266. supply 5 V

Comment: I't wooorkeed ;) Thaank you alot :)))))))))))

Comment: the purpose of the adapter is to convert 5 V power and logic level on RX pin to 3.3 V of the esp-12F